# ggplot2 - geom_bar with border = NA

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to produce stacked plots with `ggplot2` and I can't get rid of **white** thin lines between bars.

With the base `barplot` function, using the argument `border = NA` gives me what I want (figure on the right)

```
barplot(df, border = NA, space = 0, col = c('orange', 'khaki'), main = 'border = NA')
```

[image]

However, I can't figure out with `ggplot2` to get these borders to disappear.

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(dplyr) 
library(broom) 
library(reshape2) 

df %>% melt() %>% ggplot(aes(Var2, value, fill = factor(Var1))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',  width=0.9) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('orange', 'khaki')) + theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Any idea?

I don't want the `geom_area` solution

```
geom_area(stat = 'identity',  position = "stack")
```

## the data

```
sq = round( sort(rnorm(100, 50, 10)))  
df = matrix(0, 2, 100)
df[1, ] = sq
df[2, ] = 100 - sq
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `width` in the `geom_bar` layer is set to `0.9`. If you set it to `1.0` the bars will fill the space and the borders will disappear.

```
df %>% melt() %>% ggplot(aes(Var2, value, fill = factor(Var1))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', width = 1) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('orange', 'khaki')) + theme_minimal()
```

[image: plot]

[From the `geom_bar` documentation:](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html)

> **width** Bar width. By default, set to 90% of the resolution of the data.